# Working with git submodules/cocoapods

Tags: ios, github, repository, git-submodules, cocoapods

I am working on a project which includes other repositories from Git.

I would like to keep up to date with these repositories. Know what are the latest features, bug fixes etc. 
Qu 1) What is the best way to keep up to date with a repository on Git without receiving emails of all issues reported etc?

After this is complete I would like to know the best way to include these into your project. I understand you can copy the source code into the project, but what are cocoapods/sub modules used for? For example, what is the correct way to update your project with the latest changes to that included repository?

Are there any GUIs for either of these methods as opposed to terminal?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) is a great way to include other projects in your Xcode project. The Cocoapods project maintains a list of [*pod spec*](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) files for a many open source libraries, which specify where to download the code and how to integrate them into an existing project. As you noted, you'd traditionally have to add a `git submodule`, manually add the source files to your project, update your build settings, and so forth. Cocoapods takes care of all of this for you.

I'm not sure of a way to track updates for Github projects without also being notified about issues, but Cocoapods can certainly tell you if any of your 'pods' have become outdated. It's then one command to update them to the latest versions. That said, it's generally [best practice](http://9elements.com/io/index.php/cocoapods-best-practices/) to 'lock' your external dependencies to a specific version that you know works correctly.

### Using Cocoapods

To get started, first [install Cocoapods](http://docs.cocoapods.org/guides/installing_cocoapods.html). You then simply need to create a file in your root project directory (the same directory that contains your `.xcodeproj` file) called `Podfile`. Inside, you can specify your target OS, and your dependencies:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '0.9.1'
pod 'OHAttributedLabel', '0.1.1'
```

The example above is targeting iOS 5.0, and pulling in the *AFNetworking* and *OHAttributedLabel* projects.

Then, in the Terminal, change to your project directory:

```
> cd path/to/my/project
```

And run `pod install`.

```
> pod install
```

This will check out the latest version of your dependencies for you. It will also generate you a `.xcworkspace` file. From now on, when you work on your project, **you must open the .xcworkspace, not the .xcodeproj file**.

Inside your new workspace, you'll have your existing Xcode project and a new `Pods` project - this contains all of your third party libraries. Just build and run your app as normal, and the Pods project will also be built and included.

Some other useful Cocoapods commands:

```
> pod outdated
```

Will list all dependencies that have an update available.

```
> pod search query
```

Will search all known Pod specs for 'query'. Useful for finding new libraries!

### Tutorials

- Looks like Tutsplus have a nice [tutorial on getting started with Cocoapods](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/streamlining-cocoa-development-with-cocoapods/)
- There's a [free episode of NSScreencast on Cocoapods](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/5-cocoapods)

### GUIs

I'm afraid I don't know of any GUIs for Cocoapods, but there really aren't many Terminal commands that you need to know. It's worth getting comfortable with the command line, as it's such a useful developer tool.

That said, as far as I know, [Appcode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) ([Jetbrains'](http://www.jetbrains.com) alternative IDE for Objective-C) is planning on adding Cocoapods support in their next update.

Good luck!

Comment: Right now there's a new Plugin for Xcode to manage CocoaPods. You should at it in GUIs. It located at https://github.com/kattrali/cocoapods-xcode-plugin

Comment: Good answer. However, I think it's very important to note that most of the Pods are out-of-date. For some reason, many projects just "forget" to update their pods. So always check with the main repo that your pods are actually the latest build.

Comment: thanks for explaining CocoaPods! I wish you had given the other option, git submodules, the same kind of a treatment, or at least a sentence of comparison

Comment: Another advantage Cocoapods have over git submodules is the interface to customizing how a sub-project is built is more simple with Cocoapods. As a pod creator one can provide subspec that customize what set of source files are provided and what preprocessors are specified in a cumulative way.

Answer (score 17):

James Frost's answer is an excellent explanation of how to work with Cocoapods and their advantages over submodules.

A few important advantages submodules have over Cocoapods are:

**submodules are sub-repos** - not only does this mean that git and git GUIs implicitly recognize them and more and more support easily working with them, it also means that your dependencies stay connected the wonderful world their git repos, Cocoapods or not, reside in. This means that you are able to collaborate and test changes from within your project, your project usually being the source of inspiration for elaboration of a dependency.

Unfortunately Cocoapods do not maintain this link, to work on a dependency means to clone it from git, outside of the range of Cocoapods. 
**Edit:** It's worth noting that Cocoapods does allow working on a local pod with the `path` or `local` fields or even building your own Spec repo but it still isn't as simple a process.

**one less tool dependency** - as mentioned in the previous bullet, submodules are a function of git and your using git means they are available to you. Any software's adoption of git implies that they will eventually support either all (important) features of git or all features that cover common use cases. Xcode 5 has brought in a basic support for git and GUIs (which are tool dependencies, it's true, but hopefully just dictate how information is surface, git dictates how it works) like Git Tower make working with sub-repos straightforward.

Cocoapods has come a long way and everyday is taking steps to becoming a stable, indispensable tool. However it hasn't yet gotten a nod from Apple and there isn't any reason why Apple won't release a change to Xcode that breaks Cocoapods. Additionally Cocoapods is dependant on Ruby. *Aside, considering how much attention and community has been generated around Cocoapods it would be silly for Apple to ignore it.*

---

It's also worth noting that using one does not lock you out of using the other. It might be a headache or it might be what you need, perhaps using Cocoapods for tiny one class libraries or libraries with complex dependancies and submodules for libraries with that you will be interacting with often.

Comment: great points. I don't believe its fair to omit or gloss over these advantages that submodules have over Cocaopods. I am highly skeptical Apple will ever add support for them (would be happy to go into detail) though I don't really think this is the most relevant factor for deciding to use one option over the other. the two points you mention, however, settle the debate for me

Comment: It's got the nod now, Apple's Github projects ResearchKit and CareKit use it.